# Why do I get 'No module named 'currency-symbols' when importing xls2xlsx, even though 'pip install currency-symbols' returns requirement satisfied?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, miniconda

My IDE is Spyder and the distribution I am using is miniconda. I use pip install in the anaconda prompt window (as I usually do).

'pip install xls2xlsx' seems to run fine and install the package.

When I try 'from xls2xlsx import XLS2XLSX' I get the following error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'currency-symbols'

If I try 'pip install currency-symbols' , I get:
'Requirement already satisfied: currency-symbols in c:\users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (2.0.2) '

I can see both directories in the site-packages directory.

Comment: `currency-symbols` is not a valid import module name, so that code should have produced a SyntaxError.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback.

Answer (score 6):

So I had the same or very similar problem,  my trace-back said it could not import currency_symbols. I found that the module it was trying to import was the constants from that package.  So I went into the py file where xls2xlsx had the issue
"htmlxls2xlsx.py"   my traceback said line 40..

> currency_symbols_constants =
> importlib.import_module('currency-symbols.constants')

I noticed this was part of an 'exception' so I fixed line 37 from `import currency_symbols.constants as currency_symbols_constants` to `import currency_symbols._constants as currency_symbols_constants`

Now it imports just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I also had version 2.0.2 of currency-symbols installed, but my working host was using 2.0.1. I discovered that if you install 2.0.1, the issue did not occur.

`pip3 install -Iv currency-symbols==2.0.1`